# React Native ActivityIndicator causing high CPU load and overheating

Tags: android, react-native, cpu-usage, genymotion, activity-indicator

I'm using **React Native** component **ActivityIndicator** to display a preloading state. However, if this state persists for a few moments longer than expected (or app get stuck in the preloading state) my CPU starts to rapidly overload. You might think that this is due to some computation in the background, but this happens even when I just render it like this...

```
<View>
      <ActivityIndicator color="white" size="small"/>
      <Text>Connecting...</Text>
</View>
```

I'm using emulated device (S. Galaxy S6, API 23) in Genymotion emulator on Mac OSX 10.12.1
The process, which drains the CPU is **Vboxheadless**

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this, or how to fix it?
Am I doing something wrong or missing some settings?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. The ActivityIndicator component from react-native is hogging my CPU. I'm using the Android Studio emulator on OSX, and the device does not seem to matter.